# Display prices for registered users only in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.8

I'm using Magento CE, and I want to know if is it possible de hide prices, and display them for only registered users, and should I doing for ??

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use standard methods to display prices you can do this with observers.

Define observers in your module config.xml

```
<catalog_product_collection_load_after>
    <observers>
        <hide_price_list_collection>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>your_module/observer</class>
            <method>listCollection</method>
        </hide_price_list_collection>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_collection_load_after>
<catalog_product_load_after>
    <observers>
        <hide_price_product>
            <type>singleton</type>
            <class>your_module/observer</class>
            <method>productLoadAfter</method>
        </hide_price_product>
    </observers>
</catalog_product_load_after>
```

And in observer class create methods:

```
public function listCollection(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $collection = $observer->getEvent()->getCollection();
        foreach ($collection->getItems() as $_item ) {
            $_item->setCanShowPrice(false);
        }
    }
    return $this;
}

public function productLoadAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    if (!Mage::helper('customer')->isLoggedIn()) {
        $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $product->setCanShowPrice(false);
    }
    return $this;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to update your list.phtml for category pages and view.phtml for product pages:

```
 <?php
     if ($this->helper('customer')->isLoggedIn() ) {
         $showprice = "style=display:block";
     } else { 
         $showprice = "style=display:none";
 }?>
     <div id="your-price-container" <?php echo $showprice;?> > </div";
```